# JPA/Hibernate: Map Unidirectional OneToOne with Foreign Key Column in opposite table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

## My Question

Is there a way to map this relation in an uni-directional style without introducing bidirectional mappings in my code?

## Background:

I'm trying to add a 1:1 Relation to an existing Entity/Table **A**. The table should not be changed, so the column to join is located in the new table **B**. The Resulting E/R-Model looks like this:

[image: ER-Diagram of the described tables]

Inside my Application the Access direction will always be A->B so I added a field in my Class A:

```java
class A {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name="B", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TABLE_A_ID"))
    private B relation;
}
```

However Hibernate does not recognize the mapping and throws an exception at startup.

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [b_id] in table [B]
```

I know this is not the "normal" way where the owning side of the Entity-Relation corresponds to the  "owning" side of the database. But is there a way to map this so i don't have the hassle and pitfalls of bi-directional-Relationships?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Why do you think JPA requires bidirectional relationships at all? Your issue here is that an A->B mapping where B has a fk to A requires definition with a join column to describe the FK in B - not a JoinTable. JoinTable means you have a relational table in-between A and B, which is normally used for ManyToMany relationships. What you are mapping is common in OneToMany mappings, as (unless you put a uniqueness constraint on the fk) multiple Bs can point to the same A. See examples on Unidirectional OneToMany mappings

Comment: @Chris thanks for the Input. I indeed didn't need the Join Table Annotation, I tought it could be used to hint hibernate to search the foreign key in the opposite table. What helped was to add `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`. Hibernate now correctly identifies the mapping but still seems to have errors when generating queries but that's another problem.

Comment: PrimaryKeyJoinColumn isn't what you should be using as a regular JoinColumn is fine, since you are marking it as updatable,insertable=false. PrimaryKeyJoinColumn means something different, even if it is sometimes put to this same purpose in JPA 1.0 apps. Note though that you are still responsible for finding a way to get a value into B's TABLE_A_ID column. Your A->B OneToOne mapping won't do it (but it might if you made it a unidirectional OneToMany). The only way to specify the FK is on the target entity is using mappedBy, which requires a mapping on the inverse side to define the relation.

Comment: After a brief moment of hope I too realized  `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` won't help me there. I Can confirm the unidirectional oneToMany works and can be hidden by providing custom getters and setters. But in the end I probably just use a bidirectional OneToOne as it is easier to understand.
@Chris Thank you again for the extra Information